# Multiline QInputDialog prompt

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently using something like this:

```
QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("title"),"Hello World !! What goes in here",  QLineEdit::Normal, QString(""), &ok);
```

Now I want the text in the Dialog

```
"Hello World !! What goes in here"
```

to be spread over two lines. like this

```
        Hello World !! 
       What goes in here
```

Any suggestions on what I could do ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply insert a line break:

```
"Hello World!!\nWhat goes in here"
```

The complete compileable example shows why sometimes using an application framework isn't that bad of an idea. It's no longer than a comparable command-line variant would be, assuming that you had a proper, Unicode-based standard library to start with.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QInputDialog::getText(nullptr, "Title", "Hello World !!\nWhat goes in here");
    return 0;
}
```